# Avoiding errors at runtime

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-7

I have a lot of commands in one procedure and there is this command:

```
...
Stream:=TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmOpenread);
...
```

The whole procedure is created to send file from TClientSocket to TServerSocket.

The procedure is launching every 100 milliseconds from Timer. Of course, sometimes I have EFCreateError error showing because the file is used.

Everything works well because some data is received. But how to avoid showing this error?

Comment: Maybe:     try
Size:=TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmOpenRead);
except
on E: EFCreateError do {nothing} end;....

Comment: Does your procedure open the same file every time it is called? If you open the same file several times, then you can open the file once (outside that particular procedure), and then read/write from/to the file several times.

Comment: @Robrok, don't **ever** apologize for your English, 90% of the world is NOT english and this is an international forum. If we know what you mean then that's fine. And besides, your English is really good.

Comment: @Johan By my calculations, less than 1% of the world is English.

Comment: @Robrok, in the fact, that remark **attracted** grammar nazis, instead of **repulsing** them from picking at the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the error and handle it.
See the code below.

```
....
try
  Stream:=TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmOpenread); 
except on E: EFCreateError do
  Stream:= nil;
end; {try}
if Stream <> nil then try
  //rest of your procedure
finally  
  Stream.Free; //make sure your stream is freed.
end;
```

If there's an error here, no message will be shown in runtime, in debug you will see an error, but you can ignore that.
On error the `Stream` variable will be set to nil.
In the code that follows you can test `Stream <> nil` or `Assigned(Stream)` *(which is the same)* and do stuff with the stream if all is well.

Comment: But if happens exceptios my all procedure will broke because its using the stream.

Comment: @Robrok, NO. That's why you're doing the `if stream = nil` test. You only run the rest of your code `if stream <> nil` that way you are 100% stream was created OK.

Comment: @Robrok, the except will catch any and all exceptions and eliminate them so the rest of the code does not notice, that's why you're setting Stream = nil in the `except` part.

Comment: This code will leak memory every time an exception occurs, because it will not reach the Stream.Free

Comment: @mjn, if the constructor fails, the object never gets created, so no memory leak occurs, but just to make you happy I've added extra code.

Comment: My mistake, sorry - the additional code could be simply `except // do nothing end;`

Comment: Robrok's comment on the question has it right: Catch only `EFCreateError`, not *all* exceptions. That's the only exception this code is really prepared to do anything about. All other exceptions should propagate up to the caller, or at least be handled differently.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, Forgot that TFileStream.Create can also generate EFOpenError.

Comment: OK, then catch both exception types. The point is to not catch *all* exceptions. Catch only the types you expect to be thrown, and then only the ones you're prepared to handle right there.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, the only one realistically left is EOutOfMemoryError, and we don't usually test for that...?

Comment: Of course you don't test for that. What could you realistically do when you catch it? A function whose job is to send files over a socket, like the one here, shouldn't be saddled with the burden of memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you mean...

You do handle the exceptions properly, but you want to avoid the Delphi IDE popup for each and every exception that occurs.

If so, do the following:

1. Go to Tools -> Debugger Options
2. Go to the Language Exceptions tab
3. Add EFCreateError to the list of exceptions to ignore

Comment: At runtime, not while programing!!

Comment: @Robrok: Elling's answer applies to run-time exceptions.

Comment: @Andreas, @Robrok, run-time exceptions during debugging. Not run-time exceptions during stand alone running outside of the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap the access to the file in a mutex or a read/write lock? Then you wouldn't need to rely on a brittle approach like this.

It also sounds like you are polling a file as an inter process communication mechanism. Something like a pipe is likely to be much more effective.

Answer (score -2):

Using try ... finally to cleanup and try ... except to swallow the expected exception:

```
  Stream := nil; // if it is an unitialized local variable, assign nil
  try
    try
      Stream := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenread);
    except         
      on E: EFCreateError do
      begin
        // exception thrown if the file is in use
        // and may be ignored in this function
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end
```

Comment: this code will give an error on Stream.Free, if the create was not successful.

Comment: -1. Delphi 101. That's simply not how exceptions and constructors work.

Comment: `TObject.Free` checks if the object pointer is `nil`, and only calls `Destroy` if it is not